# TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined on Angular, where? Using Cloud9

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cloud9-ide

I'm new at angular. I started a new proyect at [cloud9](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0p5zr6fzKAhXHEpAKHWQ9BL8QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fc9.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNHeXGx8w99yPGVSzgrH-Wa2kB_mQw&sig2=6GxFzQQFEuyIH1CwoNHd0g&bvm=bv.114195076,d.Y2I), things work, but i'm getting an error in chrome's console. I started by erasing lots of lines of code and now i have just two lines on js and I still can't detect where is the problem. Im sure it is a stupid mistake, but i'm sutcked.

**Can you please tell me where does this error come's from?**

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined
>       at arguments.(anonymous function) (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2001:19)
>       at m.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:138:399)
>       at m.scopePrototype.$digest (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2016:23)
>       at m.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:341)
>       at m.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2079:22)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:21:44
>       at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:295)
>       at Ac.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:20:468)
>       at Object.Ac.ia.resumeBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:21:357)
>       at maybeBootstrap (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:569:11)

```js
angular.module("appAgenda", [])
  .controller("article-categories-list", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.categories = "asd";
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appAgenda" lang="es">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="article-categories-list as ctrl" class="row"><span ng-bind="categories"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:** While changing the code to isolate the problem with the code snippet i realized that it throws no error.
But still getting that error using cloud9. The issue could be there..

Comment: One thing you have injected the getDBInfo in  article-categories-list controller but you haven't include the dbInfo module.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that! I've changed the code now

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you forgot to inject $http possibly also getDBInfo

```
angular.module("appAgenda", [])
  .controller("article-categories-list", ["$scope","$http"
    function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.categories = "asd";
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the problem isn't there. That kind of error throws a  dependency inyection error or something like that, the error im getting is a TypeError form js. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Solved running the exactly same code in a local server. The problem is at c9...

Comment: Cloud9 just doesn't sense libraries in external files so it'll throw warnings about thing like this. You can ignore these with a regex in settings.